# WCF acted as single threaded inspite of multiple concurrency mode

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, concurrency

I have a WCF service deployed to IIS 6. This service calls another web services that returns bytes. I return those bytes to the client. When the byte size exceeds and it takes little longer time, WCF acts like single threaded and there is delay in response to the multiple clients running at the same time. The MSDN suggests to use Windows Service to host the service: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/26530d10-0328-42d9-a574-6d79734828e8

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Is the other service that is being called limiting calls to one at a time?

Comment: No, the other services handles concurrently. To make sure I tested with 12mb file on the disk directly without calling other service and I found that when I ran two clients at the same time with 3sec pause, i saw the time just got doubled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control concurrency with the `ServiceBehavior` attribute on the service implementation class.

E.g.:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{   
    ... implementation ...
}
```

Comment: I have configured the ServiceBehavior appropriately like you have mentioned. And it works fine too. The problem is only when it reads/response larger bytes.